# MySQL Error: Unhandled exception: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: mysql, google-sheets

I downloaded a Google Sheets workbook as a CSV file and tried to import it as a table in my MySQL Workbench, but I keep getting this error...

Unhandled exception: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

I've tried to export it/save it differently multiple times, but nothing has worked.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: It looks like it's a character set incompatibility. Are you defining the table with sql statements? Then explicitly change the charset of the column or table. If using the workbench interface, try changing the charset for the column or table in the interface. I'm not really familiar with using the interface. I would try changing the charset for the session if neither of those work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `0xEF` value is the first byte of the [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Byte_order_mark) in the UTF-8 encoded CSV file you exported.

Specify UTF-8 text encoding instead of ASCII encoding when you import the file.

If you cannot specify which text encoding to use, convert the file to ASCII before importing. You can do that with most modern text editors, e.g., [CotEditor](https://coteditor.com/) for macOS, or [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) for Windows (see [New document](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/preferences/#new-document) and [Encoding](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/preferences/#encoding-menu)).

Comment: This worked! It looks like I had some non-ASCII characters in the file that were causing the error and your advice helped. Thank you so much! For Mac users who might need this, I used CotEditor to change the file encoding.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue with some datasets I downloaded from Kaggle. I used https://tableconvert.com/csv-to-json to convert the files into JSON and it worked all good with that.

Answer (score 3):

One workaround is just convert that csv/xls file to JSON format, and then can import via workbench.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Tried to import SPSS database into MySQL. Too complicated. Went through Excel -> .csv in order to get the utf-8 encoding. Still didn't work. Downloaded CotEditor and easily found how to change encoding. My file had utf-8 with BOM encoding, which wasn't accepted by MySQL. Changed it to utf-8 and that did the trick. Mac user here.

Comment: Same here. Issue solved by changing to "ASCII" using CotEditor.

Comment: This worked! Anyone else struggling, this is a super easy fix and the CotEditor is nice and clean.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the file with Microsoft Excel and save the file with the file format: *Comma-separated Values (.csv)*. This method solved my problem.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mysql Workbench 8.0.29+ has bug on "Table Data Import" feature.

Reference:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F773id46dXI
- https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=107319

Mysql Workbench only apply the **first option** in encoding list, even though you select a other encoding (utf8, ...etc).

If the **first option** can't decode your csv file, Mysql Workbench will throw exception then break.

In my situation, my first option is 'cp950' and my CSV file is utf-8.
Mysql Workbench throw exception and break. Even though I changed encoding to utf-8, Mysql Workbench still throw a 'cp950' exception.

I can't convert my CSV to ASCII or CP950, because my data not only ASCII / CP950 characters.

A workaround:

1. Exit Mysql Workbench
2. Open folder `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\python\lib\encodings`
3. Backup the first option encoding python files in your list. (In my situation first option is `cp950.py` and `cp950.pyc`)
4. Copy `utf_8.py`, `utf_8.pyc` and rename to `cp950.py`, `cp950.pyc`.
5. Override original `cp950.py`, `cp950.pyc` in folder.
6. Launches Mysql Workbench and Import again.

Comment: You can also remove the BOM from the file especially if it's a CSV, because the BOM is redundant: `vi -c ":set nobomb" -c ":wq" mydata.csv`

Comment: Reverting to 8.0.28 did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem - and it turned out to be spaces at the beginning of the cell.  My error was:  'ascii' codec can't decode byte Oxca in position 125: ordinal not in range(128).

i simply went to position 125, then returned to my csv and found the space, deleted, and re-imported successfully.

Answer (score 0):

For those trying to import non data that contains non-alphabetic characters (in my case it was **Japanese**).
I post [this link](https://teratail.com/questions/342987) to this issue (it is in Japanese as well). The solution was simply:

1. to run MySql Workbench from the command line
   `open /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app`
2. then **Refresh all** the schemas.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I open the csv file with a sublime editor (you can use other) and then on the top menu I opened Save with Encoding/UFT-8 . Then I wan able to import it with MySQL.  I hope this can help!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I took all of the special characters out and still had that issue.
I went to the excel file and it was saved as a .csv uft-8 file and I just changed it to a regular .csv and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

What worked on MacOS, and a solution that allows whatever encoding you want: I changed the Python file that prepares the preview, *MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/sqlide_power_import_export_be.py* , so that when its analyze_file function opens a file, it uses UTF-8 encoding which is all I'll ever use.

Change line:

`with open(self._filepath, 'r') as csvfile:`

To:

`with open(self._filepath, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:`

I had discovered that analyze_file was the offender by examining the "Show Log File" from the Help menu, which opens the error log in Console.app.

I suppose the real fix is to have the user-chosen encoding be applied when opening.